# Read coredumps without debug build

Tags: core-dump

I have an application which crashes with a SIGSYS and reading the coredump, doesn't provide any useful information, since I don't have the application in debug mode available, so all `in` statements are shown up as `??`. Is it anyhow possible to convert the 128bit hex values to more or less readable values?